# NavBar is Fixed Section heading is not soing

Tags: javascript, html, css

---

=================================

my page is like home page on web [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIN8V.png problem is on click link new: [this is my problem][1]I need page like this when click on new:[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeB1Z.png [My navbar is fixed][2] when I am click on new my section heading is covered by navbar [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpNEi.png
In This page navbar is fixed. when I am click on new my section heading is not display.
heading is covered by navbar please help
***I need code like this when we click on new***

```
**only use HTML, CSS and JavaScript**
```

**code is:**

````
**CSS of Code**
    ```* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .section {
        background-color: green;
        height: 200px;
    }

    .section1 {
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 900px;
    }

    .section2 {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 900px;
        transition: .5s;
    }```



**html of Code**
````

````
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#main" style="font-size: 3rem;">new</a>

    </div>

    <div>

        <div class="section">

        </div>

        <div class="section1">

        </div>

        <div class="section2" id="main">
            <h1>section</h1>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script>
    </script>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: In This design when click on **new** in blue section heading is not soing

Comment: Simply add a `margin-top` to your first section.

Comment: no only margin top answer is scroll-padding-top

Comment: But I Am Search **Auto calculate navbar height ** then create a space scroll padding top By Java Script

Comment: <script>
        const hei = document.getElementById('height').offsetHeight;
        console.log(hei);
        const cl = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll");
        for (let i = 0; i < cl.length; i++) {
            const h = hei + "px";
            cl[i].style.scrollMarginTop = h;
        }
    </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is The Correct Answer By **Java Script**.

### Automatic Calculate Navbar height then create padding only on scroll.

---

Automatic Calculate Navbar height and then create padding only on scroll. For This I AM using Scroll-padding-top.
**This Is Fully Complete By Java Script**
**Style Is Start Here**## Heading ##

---

---

```
<style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html {
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }

        .main {
            position: fixed;
            height: 100px;
            border: 5px solid yellow;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .green {
            height: 800px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .blue {
            height: 800px;
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .yellow {
            height: 800px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .pink {
            height: 900px;
            background-color: pink;
        }
    </style>

**HTML Is Start Here**
<body>
        <div id="height" class="main">
            <a href="#blue">home</a>
            <a href="#pink">about</a>
            <a href="#new">main</a>
        </div>
        <div class="green">
        </div>
        <div id="blue" class="blue scroll">
            <h1>home</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="pink" class="pink scroll">
            <h1>about</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="new" class="yellow scroll">
            <h1>main</h1>
        </div>
```

**script Is Start Here**

`

```
<script>
        const hei = document.getElementById('height').offsetHeight;
        console.log(hei);
        const cl = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll");
        for (let i = 0; i < cl.length; i++) {
            const h = hei + "px";
            cl[i].style.scrollMarginTop = h;
        }
    </script>
```

`

Comment: not a down vote any dough you can tock me

Comment: Sorry Using **scrollMarginTop** This is Easy

Answer (score 0):

First you should always use min-heights so that they can expand on mobile.

Then you could give a `padding-top: 150px` to the id so that it displays below the nav and set the scroll behaviour in css

```
html{
scroll-behaviour:smooth;
}
```

Copy this

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
            * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    html{
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    .nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .section1 {
        background-color: green;
        min-height: 200px;
    }

    .section2 {
        background-color: yellow;
        min-height: 900px;
    }

    .section3 {
        background-color: blue;
        min-height: 900px;
        transition: .5s;
        padding-top: 150px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#main" style="font-size: 3rem;">new</a>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <div class="section1">
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="section2">
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="section3" id="main">
                <h1>section</h1>
            </div>
    
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or copy this. It is with a container. You will see if you see the preview.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
            * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    html{
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    .nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .section1 {
        background-color: green;
        min-height: 200px;
    }

    .section2 {
        background-color: yellow;
        min-height: 900px;
    }

    .section3 {
        background-color: green;
        min-height: 900px;
        transition: .5s;
        padding-top: 150px;
    }
    .container{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#main" style="font-size: 3rem;">new</a>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <div class="section1">
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="section2">
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="section3" id="main">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```